# Extending/overriding System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient Send(message As MailMessage) method

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

**Scenario**

Around 20 ASP.net(VB) applications share the same code framework and when deployed also shares a common web.config. Throughout the various applications we use System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient/MailMessage to send e-mails and now we would like to implement an e-mail opt-out feature for our users with a minimal amount of change to the existing code. That leaves out the simplest approach; inheriting a class from SmtpClient, say OurSmtpClient, and override the Send() method to remove all users that have opted to not receive e-mails, as that would mean we would have to change all New SmtpClient() to New OurSmtpClient() throughout the apps.

**Alternatives**

We've previously used tagMapping to remap tags to our in-house, derived alternatives, are there anything similar for classes so that all SmtpClient automatically becomes OurSmtpClient and thus will use the overridden Send() method?

We've also looked at [Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163317.aspx), but the problem here is that we can't override existing methods, only add new ones?

Next alternative we have considered is reflection, but we couldn't get our minds around on how to actually implement it.

Events .. Oh, if there was a Sending event ...

**Code** (cause everyone likes it)

Here is the inherit approach, just to understand what we are looking for:

```
Public Class OurSmtpClient
    Inherits SmtpClient

    Public Overloads Sub Send(message As MailMessage)
        For i As Integer = message.To.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            With message.To(i)
                If (.Address.Contains("test")) Then
                    message.To.RemoveAt(i)
                End If
            End With
        Next

        MyBase.Send(message)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Any suggestions? How can this be done without changing the code in the existing applications and only in the shared code (lives in App_Code in the apps) or the shared web.config?

Comment: What are your priorities, to have this done with the minimal amount of work or to have this done in a flexible manner so that it can be further changed in future?

Comment: A good and valid question, Wiktor. Of course, subclassing SmtpClient leaves us in a better state with regards to adding additional functionality in the future. But it also means a lot of work now that might not be necessary. We're talking quite a few lines of code here spread throughout many apps, and although it's a matter of opening the projects in VS and Ctrl+H, it also means we have to follow our Q/A, testing and deployment routines of all these apps. So we're looking to reduce the amount of work to do this and that means only changing the shared framework and web.config.

Comment: Have you considered using an AOP framework which does statis weaving (like PostSharp)? This would require some research but chances are that your existing calls can be intercepted by the framework and then you could just create a specific advice to handle your custom logic. I don't have working examples at hand, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Wiktor. I stumbled upon that alternative, but didn't look closer into it as it required adding an additional library. As versatile as .NET is I was hoping for a one-line solution to this problem, but it seems we're out of luck on this one.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but SmtpClient.Send is not virtual, how are you going to override it?

Comment: @SimonMourier Only wishful thinking :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that you are struggling to implement what should be a straightforward requirement is a big clue that you've built up too much [technical debt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258775/what-is-technical-debt).  Your post conveys a strong reluctance to pay down technical debt.  This is something that you must avoid and instead embrace [Merciless Refactoring](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RefactorMercilessly).  Bite the bullet and introduce that specialised SMTP class.

Comment: Guess you are right ... Thanks. I was in a limbo between who should get the reward but decided to share; Grubsnik got the bounty for his efforts and you got the accepted answer. Probably someone will complain, but that's what I did.

Answer (score 2):

I would change this at the data layer instead of in the mail client.

I'm assuming you store all the information about you users somewhere centrally, along with the information that they would rather not receive any further emails. So in my eyes, the chance would be to simple no longer return those users whenever you ask for the list of users to send emails to.

I don't know enough about the way your current applications work, but that does seem like the most convenient place to change it.

Comment: +1.. At the sending function is the last place I would prevent sending email's to those who unsubscribed. Of course if there's no choice then its something else...

Comment: Good idea, and yes, we store it centrally. However, this would require many code changes since we use different ways to send e-mails and get the users/e-mails that should receive them. Taking away the requirement "minimal amount of change...", we have many options (including what you suggest). But we are hoping to avoid this, and that is why I'm asking this question. From Git stats we've got roughly 350K lines of code. Combine that with testing, Q/A and release management and you've got many, many man hours. That is why I was looking towards SmtpClient since that's the common denominator.

Comment: My angle was to modify the stored procedures getting the data from the database. Reviewing a set of stored procedures which still return data in the same format would mean you didn't have to go through QA and verification of the entire application code base.

Comment: True, @Grubsnik, however, we don't have SPs that are specifically aimed at getting users to e-mail. They are more generic, like GetUsersForApp and are used for multiple purposes, including e-mail sending. Thanks for your suggestion, though!